# Firefox: floating element in dropdown showing wrong

Tags: css, firefox, zurb-foundation-5, megamenu

See here: [codepen.io/arnaudfabs/pen/waXWJL](http://codepen.io/arnaudfabs/pen/waXWJL)`enter code here`

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 to build a mega menu. I need the item name and its price on the same line for each product.

I added a **span float right** for the price and it shows well on Chrome and IE.

In Firefox, the price is going out of the **li tag** and is not even clickable.

See pictures:

**Good:**
[image]

**Bad:**
[image]

Any thoughts on what to do?? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your HTML and CSS? Or better yet make a Fiddle of the problem?

Comment: There you go:  http://codepen.io/arnaudfabs/pen/waXWJL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the style `white-space: nowrap;` on `.top-bar-section .dropdown li a` seems to fix your problem in FireFox.

or just override it like this:

```
.top-bar-section .dropdown li a{
    white-space: normal;
}
```